# Estimating variation in a given proportion across multiple experiments

Tags: proportion

I have stimuli which vary (lets say that the stimuli range -10 to + 10).
I also have a single reference stimulus (value = 0).
I want to measure the accuracy with which people can discriminate each of the 20 stimuli from the reference.  The data i collect is binary, they tell me if the stimulus is 'lower' or 'higher' than reference.

For the stimuli at the ends of the range (+10 and -10) i expect people preform with 100% accuracy (because these are very different from the reference).  I've run a test with 20 people and found that this is the case.

Is there a way i can use this data to show that if i do this test multiple times i'm always going to get 100% accuracy at the ends of the range? or (more realistically) can I at least say that accuracy at the ends of the range will not be less than a certain value (e.g it will not be less than 90%).

I need to make sure i have a range that will always span high accuracy (over 90%) - low accuracy

How would i go about doing this?  Is a test of equivalence appropriate? Thanks in advance for your help